# Symfony2 serialize() Error at offset

Tags: php, symfony, rabbitmq

I'm trying to serialize an php array to xml, but something is waaay off here. Problem might be rabbitmq -related too.. Had similar errors before after implementing the rabbitmq into the system.

The code:

```
$encoders = array(new XmlEncoder(), new JsonEncoder());
$normalizers = array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer());
$serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

if($return_type == "xml")
{
      // Create xml-response out of the information found, and return it:
      return $serializer->serialize($options, 'xml');
}
else if($return_type == "json")
{
      // Create json-response out of the information found, and return it:
      return $serializer->serialize($options, 'json');
}
```

The error:

> Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 30 bytes
>
> 500 Internal Server Error - ContextErrorException

The json-part works just fine, but serializing to xml gives the error. What am I missing here?

**Edit:**
Part of stacktrace of the error.

> [2015-10-05 12:37:13] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException: "Notice:
>   unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 30 bytes" at
>   C:\wamp\www\Projects\myproject\v.0.1\vendor\oldsound\rabbitmq-bundle\OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\RpcClient.php
>   line 63 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ContextErrorException(code: 0):
>   Notice: unserialize(): Error at offset 0 of 30 bytes at
>   C:\wamp\www\Projects\myproject\v.0.1\vendor\oldsound\rabbitmq-bundle\OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\RpcClient.php:63)"}
>   []

**Edit2:**
There seems to be something else going on in here. It shows this in the full stacktrace:

> vendor\oldsound\rabbitmq-bundle\OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\RpcClient.php'‌​,
>   '63', array('msg' => object(AMQPMessage), 'messageBody' => 'error:
>   Invalid Character Error'))

Why is that there?

**Edit3:**
I put some echoes into the code, just before the serializing, and righ after it, and it print the first but not the second.

```
echo "TESTING, ROW: ".__LINE__;
$xml = $serializer->serialize($options, 'xml');
echo "TESTING, ROW: ".__LINE__;
```

I also put that code inside try-catch, but it's not giving any errors from that..? There is something shady going on in here..

**Edit4:**
I tried the serializer with something simple like this:

```
$xml = $serializer->serialize(array("test"=>1), 'xml');
```

And that seems to work just fine. This makes me wanna ask: what characters doesn't the serializer like in the original array? Unfortunately I cannot show the insides of the array, but if anyone has some ideas about non-acceptable chars when using serializer, I'd be happy to hear.

Comment: Are you sure that the error is caused by the above code block? I doubt that a *serializing* process would use *unserializing* functionality.

Comment: @lxg When I change the `serialize($options, 'xml');` to `serialize($options, 'json');`, it works. I think it has something to do with the rabbitmq being an ***hole again. That's why I put it into the tags as well.

Comment: Can you catch the exception and give us a stack trace?

Comment: Exception points to the rabbitmq, which it has done several times before, even if the problem wasn't there. But I'll update the question with the full error.

Comment: Uh, that's not a stack trace. The stack trace would show the chain of functions/methods called to get to the error. You can get the trace by catching the exception, then dumping the output to the browser or some file with `$e->getTraceAsString()`.

Comment: I'd rather not put the full stacktrace in here for it would show too much about the system developed. Company I work for would not appreciate it. But now that I actually look at the full stack trace and stop focusing on the given error, I can see this: `vendor\oldsound\rabbitmq-bundle\OldSound\RabbitMqBundle\RabbitMq\RpcClient.php', '63', array('msg' => object(AMQPMessage), 'messageBody' => 'error: Invalid Character Error'))` Why is the message like that?

Comment: can you post the generated xml?

Comment: @Matteo Sorry can't do that. Sort of classified information.

Comment: @Matteo Well actually it doesn't generate any xml because it stops there, and I cannot show the contents of `$options` -array.

Comment: I would guess that the `$options` variable contains an object which has its own implementation of `Serializable`, and this implementation does something funny. It's hard to be more specific without a real stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the serializer didn't like my array keys. I had keys that had spaces in them like this:

```
array("spaced key" => $data);
```

When I changed the keys to this:

```
array("spaced_key" => $data);
```

it started to work.